# Using the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ to find the Taylor series for another function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to use the Taylor Series of $\ln(1+x)$ to find the Taylor series of $f(x,y) = \ln(1+x^2y)y$ at the point $a = (0,0)$.

$$\ln(1+X) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}X^n.$$

Hence when $X = x^2y$, then

$$\ln(1+x^2y) = y\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x^2y)^n.$$

Then if I am trying to find the $3^{\text{rd}}$-order Taylor polynomial, it should simply be $$x^2y^2 - \frac{x^3y^3}{3} + \frac{x^4y^4}{3} - \frac{x^5y^5}{4}.$$

Would this approach be correct, or do I need to find the polynomial from definition? The partials for this function become over-zealously ugly for a $3^{\text{rd}}$-order polynomial approximation.

Comment: You forgot exponent $2$ over $x $.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You wrote $(xy)^n)$ instead of $(x^2y)^n $.

Comment: Woops!! Good catch.

Comment: Your final expression needs more adjustment: e.g. $y(x^2y)^2=x^4y^3$ not $x^3y^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right approach. Once you have the correct formula, simply rearrange to get a formula of the form
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^na_{n,k}x^ky^{n-k},$$
and then your Taylor polynomial of order $N$ is simply
$$T_N(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=0}^na_{n,k}x^ky^{n-k}.$$
In the case $N=3$, we in fact have $T_3(x,y)=0$. See if you can find $T_4$ which is the smallest nonzero polynomial.